# Drawing over the mac os x desktop

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to obtain this effect (on MAC OS X) : I want to draw , lets say a triangle (CoreGraphics) on the screen. This would be over the desktop, in a non-interactive invisible window. This window will always be the last in the window stack (over the desktop, never over any other window). The user should not be able to alt-tab to it. It shouldn't even be visible in the dock. The user will select attributes for it from a configuration prefpane ... Most events (right mouse click ,etc) should be forwarded to the mac desktop, Expose/Mission control and spaces need to be taken into account. 
Any good guides/tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: And what have you tried? And *how* should Exposé/Mission Control be taken into account? How do you want your window to behave with those?

Comment: Don't show anything then... that would be the behavior in expose mission controll

Answer (score 3):

Well first off your going to want to set the level of your window. 
NSWindow has lots of options. 
Experiment to find the one suited to you. 
Window appearing in Expose and mission control is configurable in Interface Builder.

You probably want a full screen window of some sort. There are many approaches to that.

You likely also want a borderless window. That's covered well elsewhere.

Then you will want to look at ways to run your app with less of the standard stuff. 
This is configurable a number of ways and widely discussed. NSApplication and NSWorkSpace give you much of that and some things can be done in the Info.plist

Lastly, you will likely want either a Status Menu item (widely over done like filters the first time everyone learns photoshop). 
Or maybe a preference pane in System Preferences. Or a global kb shortcut the invokes a prefs window.

That should be more than enough leads to get you started. Google and tinker around. Piece by piece.